# How to get recurring events from a Sharepoint 2010 List as distinct items using CAML into SSRS 2008 datasource?

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008, caml

I have a datasource in SSRS 2008 pointing to my Sharepoint list and I'm trying to get recurring events as distinct items from a calendar in a Sharepoint 2010 list using CAML query,

Example:

Event 1: 01/01/2017 15:00 Recurrent every day
Event 2: 02/01/2017 17:00 No recurrent

Expected:

( 3 Rows )

1 | Event 1 01/01/2017 15:00

2 | Event 1 02/01/2017 15:00

3 | Event 2 02/01/2017 17:00

Actual Result:

1 | Event 1 01/01/2017 15:00

2 | Event 2 02/01/2017 17:00

CAML Query:

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>Calendario</ListName>
  <ViewFields>      
      <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
      <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
      <FieldRef Name="Department" />
      <FieldRef Name="ParticipantsPicker" />
      <FieldRef Name="Facilities" />
      <FieldRef Name="Category" />
      <FieldRef Name="Title" />
      <FieldRef Name="Description" />
      <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceData" />
      <FieldRef Name="fRecurrence" />
  </ViewFields>
  <Query>
        <QueryOptions>
        <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence> 
    </QueryOptions>
    <Where>
        <IsNotNull>
                <FieldRef Name="Facilities" />
            </IsNotNull>
                      <DateRangesOverlap>
                                  <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
                                  <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
                                  <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
                            <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue="FALSE"><Month /></Value>
                            </DateRangesOverlap>
       </Where>
       <OrderBy>
         <FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' />
       </OrderBy>   
  </Query>
</RSSharePointList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CAML is mal-formed; the `<QueryOptions>` element is a **sibling** of the `<Query>` element, not a child. Try again with this revised CAML:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <IsNotNull>
            <FieldRef Name="Facilities" />
        </IsNotNull>
        <DateRangesOverlap>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' />
            <FieldRef Name='EndDate' />
            <FieldRef Name='RecurrenceID' />
            <Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue="FALSE">
                <Month />
            </Value>
        </DateRangesOverlap>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' />
    </OrderBy>   
</Query>
<QueryOptions>
    <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence> 
</QueryOptions>
```